# Shared objects without the function arguments usage

Tags: haskell

I have a few functions (some of them are nested) in the `do` block, which have a shared object (for example, a user session):

```
main = do
    session <- establishConnection
    user <- getUser
    firstFunction user session
    secondFunction session

firstFunction user session = do
    options <- getOptions
    nestedFunction options session
```

I want to avoid a many duplicated arguments in the functions, so how can I pass a `session` object into the `firstFunction`/`secondFunction`/`nestedFunction` without a function argument usage? E.g.:

```
main = do
    session <- establishConnection
    user <- getsUser
    firstFunction user

firstFunction user = do
    session <- someMagic
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if your functions will change or not the "shared object" you can use a `Reader` monad or a `State` monad. The first one in case the "shared object" is read-only, the second one if you want to read and modify the "shared object". I'm going to do an example with the `Reader` because it is easier:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

data Config = Config {
    user :: String
  , session :: Session
  }

type ConnectionState a = ReaderT Config IO a

firstFunction :: ConnectionState ()
firstFunction = do
    conf <- ask
    -- do something with conf
    return ()

secondFunction :: ConnectionState ()
secondFunction = do
    conf <- ask
    -- do something with conf
    return ()

realMain :: ConnectionState ()
realMain = do
    firstFunction
    secondFunction

main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- establishConnection
    user <- getUser
    runReaderT realMain (Config user conn)
```

The `Config` data type is the information that you want to pass to the functions, feel free to add or delete fields there. The `ConnectionState` is the `Reader` monad that you will use to "share" the `Config`. It basically encapsulate `Config` in a "read-only container". Every function has type `ConnectionState` and can use the function `ask` to read the `Config` from the monad. Note that in my example every function has type `ConnectionState ()` but you 
The `main` function is used to create a `Config` and then to call `realMain` with it. `realMain` calls all the functions involved in your program that need the `Config`.

EDIT: note that if you don' want `user` in your shared object but as argument of `firstFunction` you can remove it from `Config` and change the type of `firstFunction` to `firstFunction :: String -> ConnectionState ()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I can't understand one thing - when I have ``main :: IO ()``, ``realMain :: ConnectionState () -> IO ()`` and I'm trying to use ``runReaderT realMain (Config user conn)`` an error appears: ``Couldn't match expected type `ReaderT Config IO a0' with actual type `ConnectionState () -> IO ()'``

Comment: `realMain` should have type `ConnectionState ()`, not `ConnectionState () -> IO ()`. The type `ConnectionState ()` already "contains" IO because it is defined as `ReaderT Config IO a`. The conversion from `ConnectionState ()` to `IO ()` is done by `runReaderT` which type is `runReaderT :: ReaderT r m a -> r -> m a` where `m = IO` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

The first is probably the more accepted of the two but it is also more complicated. You use a state monad (or if you don't need to modify session a Reader monad). Since you are working in IO you need monad transformation as well to stack the two of them together.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers

The library to use is called (mtl).

The type of your functions will become:

```
firstFunction :: User -> ReaderT Session IO returntype
```

If you use this a lot in your project you can make a type synonym

```
type MyMonad a = ReaderT Session IO a
```

your someMagic function will be ask

```
firstFunction user = do
    session <- ask
```

the backdraw of this is that since the outermost monad is ReaderT if you want to perform IO, you have to lift it. This is best achieved using the liftIO function. However you don't need to do anything to run a third function of the same monad.

```
firstFunction user = do
    session <- ask
    liftIO (do some io)
    thirdFunction
```

of course you need to specify the session when you first run your monad

```
main = do
    session <- establishConnection
    flip runReader session $ do
        firstFunction
        secondFunction
```

The second ways is sort of a hack

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Top_level_mutable_state

It lets you have global IORef's, which you can access from everywhere. The advantage of this is that you can avoid all the annoying lift functions. The disadvantage is that it's a hack and that it is global :).

Answer (score 1):

A third solution is using closures: make local functions, which use `session`, with `let` inside the `do`-block:

```
main = do
    session <- establishConnection
    user <- getUser
    let firstFunction = do
        options <- getOptions
        nestedFunction options session
    let secondFunction = do
        <...>
    firstFunction
    secondFunction
```

Comment: Sounds good, but can it result to the unnecessary complexity of program?

Comment: I don't really know. IMO, nested closures, which depend on some function variables, are somewhat like object methods, which depend on its state, only less accustomed.